# Why does writing to a D3DFMT_R32F render target clamp to 1?

Tags: directx, fragment-shader, rendertargets, frame-buffer

I'm currently implementing a picking system. I render some objects in a frame buffer, which has a render target, which has the `D3DFMT_R32F` format.

For each mesh, I set an integer constant evaluator, which is its material index.

My shader is simple: I output the position of each vertex, and for each pixel, I cast the material index in float, and assign this value to the Red channel:

```
int
    ObjectIndex;
float4x4
    WvpXf : WorldViewProjection< string UIWidget = "None"; >;

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 Position : POSITION;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position : POSITION;
};

struct PS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VS_OUTPUT VSMain( const VS_INPUT input )
{
    VS_OUTPUT
        output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

    output.Position = mul( float4(input.Position, 1), WvpXf );

    return output;
}

PS_OUTPUT PSMain( const VS_OUTPUT input, in  float2 vpos : VPOS )
{
    PS_OUTPUT
        output = (PS_OUTPUT)0;

    output.Color.r = float( ObjectIndex );
    output.Color.gba = 0.0f;

    return output;
}

technique Default
{
    pass P0
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_3_0 VSMain();
        PixelShader = compile ps_3_0 PSMain();
    }
}
```

The problem I have, is that somehow, the values written in the render target are clamped between `0.0f` and `1.0f`. I've tried to change the rendertarget format, but I always get clamped values...

I don't know what the root of the problem is.

- For information, I have a depth render target attached to the frame buffer.
- I disabled the blend in the render state
- the stencil is disabled

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing your math to accommodate 0 being the minimum and 1 being the maximum?

Comment: This is lost in an old no-longer-available DX SDK - it's because you're using the COLOR0 output semantic which automatically clamps in the 0 to 1 range.

Answer (score -1):

Why are the values clamped to 0-1?  Because in non HDR rendering all pixel values are 0-1.  If you want values outside that range, you need HDR rendering.  That will, of course, *scale* the values across the whole render to fit 0-1 using fancy math, which lets the brightest brights be brighter than their surroundings without being clipped (e.g. an area being solid white or black with no definition).

In the end though, pixel values *must* be between 0 and 1 (inclusive) because *that's the maximum displayable value.*

Comment: Do you even have the slightest clue what he's talking about? He's not trying to *display* the image. It's just a data table that contains 32-bit floats. There is nothing at all wrong with what he's doing conceptually. Pixel values do not have to be between 0 and 1 because pixel values do not *have to be displayed*.